# Discord voice object has no attribute 'play'

Tags: python, discord.py

Hey I'm trying to play audio in voice chat of my discord server and I get this as error

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'play'
```

My **CODE**

```
import discord
from discord.utils import get
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import FFmpegPCMAudio
from youtube_dl import YoutubeDL
import os

@bot.command('play')
async def jp(ctx, url):
    global voice
    chan = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

 ydl_op ={
        'format':'bestaudio/best',
        'postprocessors':[{
            'key':'FFmpegExtractAudio',
            'preferredcodec':'mp3',
            'preferredquality':'256'
        }]
    }
    with YoutubeDL(ydl_op) as ydl:
        ydl.download([url])

    for file in os.listdir('./'):
        if file.endswith('.mp3'):
            name = file
            os.rename(file,'audio.mp3')

    voice.play(FFmpegPCMAudio['audio.mp3'], after=lambda e: print(f"Done playing {name}"))
    voice.source = discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(voice.source)
    voice.source.volume = 0.07

    nname = name.rsplit('-',2)**
```

there is a same question but without any verified answers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error on music discord bot in python 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'create\_ytdl\_player'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52193942/error-on-music-discord-bot-in-python-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-create)

Comment: @Ruli no, it doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code must be returning voice as `None`

**TRY THIS**

```
voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if voice and voice.is_connected:
        await voice.move_to(channel)
    else:
        voice = await channel.connect()
```